# Checkbox no funciona correctamente con Bootstrap 5 y Vuejs

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, checkbox

Presento el siguiente div el cual muestra un *input* con su *label*, el problema presenta es que no me deja hacer clic en los *checkbox*.

Este código es sólo un ejemplo de uso del checkbox de **boostrap 5** que estoy usando en **VueJs**.

```
<ul class="widget-list widget-filter-list list-unstyled pt-1" style="max-height: 11rem;"
    data-simplebar data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
  <li v-for="(brand, index) in brands" :key="index"
      class="widget-filter-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-1">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input @click="handleBrands(brand.id)"
             class="form-check-input"
             type="checkbox"
             value=""
             :id="index"
      >
      <label class="form-check-label widget-filter-item-text" :for="index">
        {{ brand.brand }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Incluso utilizo el DOM para saber si se esta marcando el checkbox pero este aun no me lo muestra:

```javascript
const brs = document.getElementById('index');
console.log(brs);
```

Comment: Recuerda incluir los estilos css y si estas usando un framework indicar nombre y versión usada.. ;)

Comment: @AndresLinares no estoy utilizando css, uso el ejemplo de boostrap 5, pero el input como el label estoy utilizando vuejs para recorrerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se pueden tener id atributos que comiencen con un número en HTML (que es lo index será).

```
:id="index"
```

La solución llame al: id = "'marcas' + índice", de esa manera si recorre el v-for también declare una variable global llamada "brand_selectd"

que puedo usar en el modelo v: ""

Variables globales:

```
data() {
        return {
            brands: [],
            brand: [],
            brand_selected: [],
        }
},
```

Y el HTML del checkbox quedo

```
                                        <input
                                            class="form-check-input"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            v-model="brand_selected"
                                            :value="brand.id"
                                            :id=" 'brands_' + index"
                                        >
                                        <label class="form-check-label widget-filter-item-text" :for="'brands_' + index">
                                            {{ brand.brand }}
                                        </label>
                                </li>
```